# iPhone Developer Portal won't accept my CSR

Tags: iphone, csr

I am using the Development Provisioning Assistant in the iPhone Developer Portal, but when I get to the part where it asks me to generate and upload my CSR, I try to upload it and it just gives me this error:

The CSR selected is invalid. Please check the file and try again.

Does anyone know what this means or what I can do about it?? Thanks!

Comment: Eh, no, but you can still try to help the guy out... 

Eamon, make sure you follow the directions very carefully. I remember the first time I did it not selecting something that should have been selected and it causing problems.

Comment: @Eamon thank you for asking this question. It's definitely programming related. Some people just don't understand what it takes to program on the iPhone. +1

Answer (score 91):

Also make sure you use Safari for uploading.

I tried Chrome and it always failed. Then I switched to Safari and it worked with the same CSR.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem.  Also, make sure you use the same email address as you registered with!

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't use the same email address I registered with. I just switched from Chrome to Safari.

Comment: +1 Fixed. I feel like the ios web sites are to safari as microsoft's website in the 90's was to IE

Comment: Thanks, that got me, and your posting saved me some sanity. :)

Comment: +1 Fixed - Apple need to but a note inside the lightbox regarding this!

Comment: Is still an issue, Chrome failed, Safari worked. Please report this issue to https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, I figured it out... in case anyone else has the same problem, I fixed it by downloading the WWDR Intermediate Certificate before generating the CSR, which I forgot to do. *slaps forehead*

Comment: This is the one that fixed it for me. Didn't work in any browser until I downloaded this.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the following menu item: "Keychain Access->Certificate Assistant->Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority", then you need a new WWDR Intermediate Certificate.  My menu item was originally similar, but had some extra text in the title.  Downloading and installing a new certificate changed the menu item and allowed generation of a valid CSR.  This was odd because my previous WWDR Intermediate Certificate appeared in my keychain as an unexpired certificate.

I logged a bug at bugreport.apple.com asking for a clearer error message and pointing back to this SO discussion. Edit: fyi.. apparently developer portal bugs should be logged by sending email to devprograms@apple.com instead of the "product" targeted bugreport website.  I encourage folks that have wasted time on this issue to provide helpful feedback regarding the issue via email.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to upload the CSR using launching assistant, try going to "Provisioning Portal -> Certificates". Upload your file there and click "submit" button at the bottom.
I had my certificate this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and what fixed it for me was to repair my login keychain.  Go to 'Keychain First Aid' in Keychain Access and you can verify/repair your config.

Answer (score 1):

Second on the Chrome vs. Safari conflict and solution.
The instructions on the iOS Provisioning Portal -> Certificates -> "How-To" tab are exactly correct, but I have a repeatable failure on upload in Chrome, and instant success on Safari.
Versions:
OS: OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.6 64-bit
Chrome: 8.0.552.237
Safari: 5.0.3 (6533.19.4)

Answer (score 1):

Did right the opposite: used Firefox instead of Safari and the button worked.

Comment: I had an error "Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Disc quota exceeded" when uploading CSR... Very strange, I tried Chrome and it worked. I probably just needed to restart Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
When creating a CSR for enabling push notifications, I first had to deselect the current selected key in Keychain Access before selecting Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority. That solved my problem

Make sure you have only "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" and not something like "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority with key "

Answer (score 0):

If under Keychain Access you only have the option for "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority with key" it will not work. This indicates you have not downloaded the "WWDR intermediate certificate". You can get it from the "Certificates" tab in the iPhone Provisioning Portal. Once its installed (double click it to install), the menu item will change to "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" and it should work.