# Getting iphone developer certificate/ Submit Certificate Signing Request

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

I'm currently using the **Development Provisioning Assistant** to setup my certificate so I can run my app on my iphone. I'm at the part in Setup called **Submit Certificate Signing Request** and it is asking me to submit the file that I generated using KeyChain Access. The problem is that it says **"The Certificate file selected is invalid"**.

I've followed its instructions to the letter and I'm not sure why the certificate would be invalid. Any ideas?

All help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994761/iphone-developer-portal-wont-accept-my-csr). Basically I was using Chrome, when I should have been using Safari :(

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that you had selected one of your private keys as you created your Certificate Signing Request.
The difference between: `Request a certificate from a certificate authority with <Your name>`
and `Request a certificate from a certificate authority...` is very subtle but if you used the first method it won't work.

Try to create another signing request and make sure that none of your private keys is selected, i.e. there are three dots behind the menu entry