# Apple developer - Invalid CSR, Invalid Certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

I generate `.certSigningRequest` file via Keychain Access (`Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority...`, I fill in my mail and I save it to disk).

When I log into Apple developer account and try to generate Certificate with it I get message: "Invalid CSR - Invalid Certificate"

## [image]

What is reason for this? Why this message appears, what could be wrong?

I've seen several StackOverflow questions like this: [iPhone Developer Portal won't accept my CSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994761/iphone-developer-portal-wont-accept-my-csr/3775958) and I haven't found solution:

- I tried downloading WWDR certificate
- I'm using Safari (but button works)
- there is only one developer certificate on account...

Comment: Have you tried in Private Browsing? OR you could check using another mac to generate new CSR and once CSR is done you can export the certificate. Also just make sure you are using same email address in the CSR as your apple ids.

Comment: @gvuksic Are you able to solve this? if yes then please post the answer so that we can get the answer and it will help others too.

Comment: Have you found a solution? This is happening for me.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I just forgot to input 'Common name' in Certificate Assistant form.

So, make sure you filled

1. User Email Address
2. Common Name
3. Saved on disk check

Answer (score 1):

After HOURS of tinkering we found that the issue is a client side (javascript) that checks for the EXACT words "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----". Our CSR had "-----BEGIN **NEW** CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" (note the word **NEW**)... After removing "**NEW**", it was accepted by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Within Keychain Access, just ensure category CERTIFICATES is selected, followed by selecting/highlighting the "Apple Worldwide Development Relations Cert Authority" entry, finally followed by requesting your cert from a CA, will resolve the invalid CSR issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete an apple WWDR(World Wide Developer Relation) certificate expiring on February 14, 2016 from your keychain (if you got one on your system), this can be found in the login tab. 
Then download the updated CSR from apple, can be found here-  https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/
Restart xCode and you will be able to regenerate a CSR normaly, deleting this expired certificate made tons of bugs in the developers tools, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Internet Explorer or Edge. Use Google Chrome or Safari on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Till recently (December '19) Firefox worked perfectly to create such certificates.

Today Firefox gave me an empty page, Edge reported this "Invalid CSR" message. **Finally Chrome did the job...**

Working on Windows 10, CSR was created with OpenSSL for a "Pass Type ID" certificate.

Answer (score -2):

The command below should print the contents of the Certificate Signing Request

```
openssl req -in certSigningRequest -text
```

If the command is not able to decode the CSR it means it was not properly generated. You might want to inspect the file with a text editor to tr to find clues about why the CSR generation failed

Comment: I get "unable to load X509 request" ?

Comment: @gvuksic: you should [edit] the relevant information into your original question - comments are temporary, and "answers" that are trying to get around the rep rules more so!

Comment: @Jofre same response  "unable to load X509 request", can you explain what is this supposed to do?

Comment: @Mogsdad sure, I'll add, I'm not sure what is this about so I just asked :)