# Invalid Certificate after Uploading CSR File

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, keychain, csr

Very Strange When I try to make any certificate by uploading csr file. It gives me error through the browser that invalid certificate. and I am not able to create certificate. but when I am doing the same thing with another machine its creating the certificate.
[I have gone through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567443/apple-developer-invalid-csr-invalid-certificate)

but I am not able to download the new CSR from apple . I think we can download new WWDR certificate.

If any one can help me in this I really fed up with this. Every time I have to use another Mac and then create new certificate from that mac and export it to p.12 file and then I can install in my Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @Arbaz have you ever try to download new WWDR  certificate?
Please try this link if you haven't tried before [WWDR Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)

Comment: @TheiOSDev I have tried to download the WWDR but still facing the same... no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserName should not be empty when you try to create CSR [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHVq.png)